# The component for route 'WELCOME' must be a React component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm kind of sure that the export-import is well done, because I use export default.
It was a working code when I had both the sign-up and log-in forms in the same page.
Now I want to navigate to two different pages through two buttons, and it gives me this error in loginIndex.js, that is the file in which I created the NavigationStack.
The fact is that it worked perfectly before adding the two new files to the stack, but now it tells me that 'Welcome' is not a React component.

### Dependencies

```
src 

/components

   /screens

     /welcome

        /index.js
 
     /sign_up

        /SignUp.js

     /login

        /login.js

/routes
 
  /loginStack.js
```

### **index.js**

```
// @flow

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  TouchableOpacity,
  StatusBar,
  Animated,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  View,
  Text,
  YellowBox,
} from 'react-native';


import Loading from '~/components/common/Loading';

import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation';

import Navigation from '~/routes/loginStack'

import ROUTE_NAMES from '~/routes/loginStack'


const Welcome = ({navigation}) => {
 

  onClickLoginButton = (): void => {
    const navigation = this.props.navigation
    navigation.navigate(ROUTE_NAMES.LOGIN)
  };

  onClickSignUpButton = (): void => {
    const navigation = this.props.navigation
    navigation.navigate(ROUTE_NAMES.SIGNUP)


  };

  onLoadBackgroundImage = (): void => {
    this.setState({
      isBackgroundImageLoaded: true,
    });
  };

    return (

      
      <Container>
        <Navigation/>
        <Loading />
        <StatusBar
          backgroundColor="transparent"
          barStyle="light-content"
          translucent
          animated
        />
        <BackgroundImage
          onLoad={this.onLoadBackgroundImage}
        />
        {isBackgroundImageLoaded && (
          <Wrapper>
            <TitleWrapper>
              <Title></Title>
            </TitleWrapper>
            <NavigationTitleWrapper>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.onClickLoginButton}
              >
                <Animated.Text
                >
                  Accedi
                </Animated.Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.onClickSignUpButton}
              >
                <Animated.Text>
                  Registrati
                </Animated.Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </NavigationTitleWrapper>
            
          </Wrapper>
        )}
      </Container>
    );
  }


export default withNavigation(Welcome);
```

### loginStack.js

```
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import Welcome from '../components/screens/welcome/index';
import MainStack from './mainStack';
import Login from '~/components/screens/log_in/Login';
import SignUp from '~/components/screens/sign_up/SignUp';

export const ROUTE_NAMES = {
  LOGIN: 'LOGIN',
  MAIN_STACK: 'MAIN_STACK',
  WELCOME: 'WELCOME',
  SIGNUP: 'SIGNUP',
};

const LoginStack = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    [ROUTE_NAMES.WELCOME]: {
      screen: Welcome,
    },
    [ROUTE_NAMES.LOGIN]: {
      screen: True_login,
    },
    [ROUTE_NAMES.SIGNUP]: {
      screen: SignUp,
    },
    [ROUTE_NAMES.MAIN_STACK]: {
      screen: MainStack,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: ROUTE_NAMES.SPLASH,
  },
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(LoginStack);

export default AppContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'setState' but using functional comoponents.
You should use hooks instead..
In addition you use 'this' but again, relevant for classes..
You are adding typescript annotations but using javascript..

Try to change the index file lto this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    TouchableOpacity,
    StatusBar,
    Animated
} from 'react-native';


import Loading from '~/components/common/Loading';

import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

import Navigation from '~/routes/loginStack'

import ROUTE_NAMES from '~/routes/loginStack'


const Welcome = ({ navigation }) => {

    const [isBackgroundImageLoaded, setIsBackgroundImageLoaded] = React.useState(false);

    onClickLoginButton = () => {
        navigation.navigate(ROUTE_NAMES.LOGIN)
    };

    onClickSignUpButton = () => {
        navigation.navigate(ROUTE_NAMES.SIGNUP)
    };

    onLoadBackgroundImage = () => {
        setIsBackgroundImageLoaded(true);
    };

    return (


        <Container>
            <Navigation />
            <Loading />
            <StatusBar
                backgroundColor="transparent"
                barStyle="light-content"
                translucent
                animated
            />
            <BackgroundImage
                onLoad={onLoadBackgroundImage}
            />
            {isBackgroundImageLoaded && (
                <Wrapper>
                    <TitleWrapper>
                        <Title></Title>
                    </TitleWrapper>
                    <NavigationTitleWrapper>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={onClickLoginButton}
                        >
                            <Animated.Text
                            >
                                Accedi
                </Animated.Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={onClickSignUpButton}
                        >
                            <Animated.Text>
                                Registrati
                </Animated.Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </NavigationTitleWrapper>

                </Wrapper>
            )}
        </Container>
    );
}

export default withNavigation(Welcome);
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, I understand the problems you are telling but it worked before adding the sign-up and log-in screen so what you suggested is not the main solution.. Thank you anyway